# Дельфи не рисует во вторичной процедуре битмап на Image.Canvas

Tags: delphi, canvas, bitmap

В первой процедуре дельфи верно рисует весь фон, однако во второй она не рисует нужный мне член массива битмапов поверх первого рисунка, хотя ошибку не выдает. Битмап вроде создал и прогрузил... помогите пожалуйста... Вот весь код:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
   Winapi.Windows,Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type


  TFormGame = class(TForm)
    PanelGameMenu: TPanel;
    TimerSpawn: TTimer;
    TimerMove: TTimer;
    LabelWave: TLabel;
    LabelGold: TLabel;
    LabelLives: TLabel;
    ImageGround: TImage;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure OnGameClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure TimerSpawnTimer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure WaveStart;
    procedure TimerMoveTimer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }        
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;


var
  FormGame: TFormGame;
  PanzerImage: array[1..4] of TBitmap;
  Gun: array[1..2] of TBitmap;
  BitMapRoad,BitMapGround,BitmapNaziBase,BitmapSovjetBase,
  PanzerToRight,PanzerToLeft,PanzerToUp,PanzerToDown:TBitmap;
  WaveNumber,TCounter: integer;
  EnemyCounter,EC1: integer;
  PanzerFaust: array of TBitmap;

implementation    
{$R *.dfm}

//процедура создания формы и инициализации рисунков    
procedure TFormGame.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);                                
var Counter1, Counter2, YY, yy2, hyy, x, y:integer;
begin    
    WaveNumber := 0;
    YY2 := 150;         //инициализация
    YY := 50;
    HYY := 50;

    BitMapRoad := TBitmap.Create;
    BitMapRoad.LoadFromFile('Road.bmp');
    BitMapGround := TBitmap.Create;
    BitMapGround.LoadFromFile('Ground.bmp');
    BitMapNaziBase := TBitmap.Create;
    BitMapNaziBase.LoadFromFile('NaziBase.bmp');
    BitMapSovjetBase := TBitmap.Create;
    BitMapSovjetBase.LoadFromFile('SovjetBase.bmp');
    PanzerToUp := TBitmap.Create;
    PanzerToUp.LoadFromFile('PanzerToUp.bmp');

    for counter1 := 1 to 20 do begin  {Начало цикла 1-го порядка} //создание травы
        for counter2:= 1 to 20 do begin {Начало цикла 2-го порядка}
            ImageGround.Canvas.Draw(Counter1*50-50, Counter2*50-50, BitMapGround);
        end;   {Конец цикла 2-го порядка}
    end;   {Конец цикла 1-го порядка}

    FormGame.Canvas.Pen.Color := clBlack;
    FormGame.Canvas.Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100);    

    for Counter1 := 1 to 5 do begin   {Начало цикла 1-го порядка} //создание спуска справа
        for Counter2 := 1 to 3 do begin   {Начало цикла 2-го порядка}
            ImageGround.Canvas.Draw(950, yy, BitMapRoad);
            yy := yy + 50;
        end;   {Конец цикла 2-го порядка}
        yy := yy + 50;
    end;   {Конец цикла 2-го порядка}    

    for Counter1 := 1 to 5 do begin   {Начало цикла 1-го порядка} //создание спуска слева
        for Counter2 := 1 to 3 do begin   {Начало цикла 2-го порядка}
            ImageGround.Canvas.Draw(0, yy2, BitMapRoad);
            yy2 := yy2 + 50;
        end;   {Конец цикла 2-го порядка}
        yy2 := yy2 + 50;
    end;   {Конец цикла 2-го порядка}

    //создание горизонтальных дорог
    for Counter1 := 1 to 10 do begin
        for Counter2 := 1 to 20 do ImageGround.Canvas.Draw(Counter2*50 - 50, HYY, BitMapRoad);
       HYY := HYY + 100;
    end;

    ImageGround.Canvas.Draw(0, 050, BitmapNaziBase);
    ImageGround.Canvas.Draw(0, 950, BitmapSovjetBase);
    WaveStart;
end;   {конец процедуры}    //конец процедуры



procedure TFormGame.OnGameClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
    BitMapRoad.Free;
    BitMapGround.Free;
    BitMapSovjetBase.Free;
    BitMapNaziBase.Free;
end;



procedure TFormGame.TimerMoveTimer(Sender: TObject);
var counter: integer;
begin
    for counter := 1 to EnemyCounter do begin
    end;
end;

procedure TFormGame.TimerSpawnTimer(Sender: TObject);
var counter:integer;
begin
    TimerMove.Enabled := true;
    if EC1<=EnemyCounter - 1 then begin
        FormGame.Canvas.Draw(50, 50, PanzerFaust[EC1]);
        EC1 := EC1 + 1;
    end;
end;

procedure TFormGame.WaveStart;
var counter:integer;
begin
    if WaveNumber < 11 then begin
        SetLength(PanzerFaust, EnemyCounter);
        for counter :=  0 to EnemyCounter - 1 do begin
            PanzerFaust[Counter] := TBitmap.Create;
            PanzerFaust[Counter].LoadFromFile('PanzerToRight.bmp');
        end;
        TimerSpawn.Enabled := True;
        EC1 := 1;
    end
    else ShowMessage('Фашистская Германия подписала акт о безоговорочной капитуляции');
end;

end.
```

Comment: Сразу учимся выражаться правильно. Процедур "первой" и "второй" нет ! и телепатов здесь нет чтобы знать какой именно член массива битмапов вам нужен!

Comment: Извините... я совсем недавно на форуме... под "первой процедурой" я подразумеваю WaveStart,  а под второй- TimerSpawnTimer. В первой процедуре я заполняю массив битмапов, а во второй пытаюсь юзать членов под номером равном переменной ЕС1. EC1:=EC1+1; Так я ввожу счетчик

Comment: Вы дебагом проходились? `EnemyCounter` У Вас чему равен?

Comment: Не испепеляйте меня пожалуйста на месте... Я не очень себе представляю, что такое "дебаг"

Comment: Тогда у меня есть для вас очень хорошие новости! Отложите все свои дела и первым делом прочитайте и поработайте с дебагом. Это пошаговая отладка программы в процессе выполнения! При должном умении пользоваться этим инструментом подобных вопросов у вас не должно будет возникать. В строчке `if WaveNumber<11 then begin` поставьте точку остановки F5, запустите программу F9. И двигайтесь постепенно по вашему коду кнопкой F8

Comment: Спасибо... сразу чувствую себя не забытым))

Comment: `if EC1<=EnemyCounter - 1` потенциально у вас тут `ec1` может произвольное значение иметь. Сначала задайте его, потом таймер запускайте. ` EC1 := 1; TimerSpawn.Enabled := True;`